# Python Printing when conditions aren't correct

Tags: python

For some reason python is printing when the conditions aren't correct.

Here is an example of my code:
config.py

```
a = 0
b = 0
verify = True
```

main.py

```
from config import a,b,verify
verify = True
current_check = 0

if verify == True:
    current_check + 1
    if a < 0:
        print(config_options[current_check]+" has an invalid value, check config.py")
        current_check + 1
```

output;

> a has an invalid value, check config.py

How is python able to print here? right above the print the variable is set to 0

Comment: This code won't run.  What is `verify`?  What is `current_check`?  When I properly define all of the undefined values, I don't see the `print` happen.  Please update your code to be something that will actually run.  Without that, it's impossible to know why you're getting the behavior you're getting.  Something else must be going on.

Comment: From what you posted, it wont print. There must be more to the story. Are you sure you're running the correct file, are you sure you saved your file, etc?

Comment: I have updated the post with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `config_options[current_check]` is not the same value as `a`.
You set `a` to 0, but you didn't do that for `config_options[current_check]`.

Comment: `config_options` is a list of all the options that can be edited in config.py.
`current_check` is what stage of this list this process is up to.
so `config_options[current_check]` gets the current config option from the currently selected item. As there are many items to check.

Comment: I don't get it, so what exactly do you expect the statement to print?